# How to read all numeric values from within a file in php?

Tags: php, css, regex

I have a CSS file with numeric values with appending px like "width: 500px;". I need to read this file from start to end using php and alter all numeric values  wherever found .i.e. convert 500px to some thing else like 50% of it (width: 250px). How can we do this, maybe using regex.

```
$file = fopen("file.css", "r+") or exit("Unable to open file!");
while(!feof($file))
{
if(numeric value between space and px)
//replace by its 50%
}
fclose($file);
```

*This code is just to explain problem, solution can be entirely different.*

Comment: Maybe you should take a look at `is_numeric()`

Comment: No `is_numeric()` doesn't work in this case.

Comment: You can probably just use php to change text in your css. Using a mycss.php file will get you variables which may be more reliable and faster than parsing with replacements. That is if this isn't a one time thing. If you need to change these values often I recommend a php file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [preg_replace_callback](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php):

```
$str = preg_replace_callback('/:\s*(\d+)px/', 
    function($m) {
        return ': '.($m[1]/2).'px';
    },
    $str);
```

Comment: Why do you need the `px`? `\b\d+` would select all numbers just fine including `em` etc...

Comment: @Robin: OP wants to convert values in px only.

Answer (score 0):

The regex you are probably looking for is

```
^[\d]*(\.\d*)?(px)?(%)?(em)?$
```

or without decimal values

```
^[\d]*(px)?(%)?(em)?$
```

This should match all the sizes.. If you want also colors (RGB/RGBA format) then take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22031819/pulling-colors-out-of-a-css-file-using-javascript/22036066#22036066) which might inspire you.

Comment: Wait, need to take into account decimal numbers.. I will update it soon.

Comment: The `[...]` are useless around `\d`, which is already a shortcut for `[0-9]`.